# Generate periodic time series of active ID based on the open ID time and close ID time

Tags: r, time-series, data-transform

I have a tibble such that for each row contains the open date and close date for an ID.
Given these 2 information, I should be able to extract how many IDs were active on each week, how many were closed on each week, and the rate of growth of active ID over the time period.

For example ID `aa` has open date on `week 1` and close date on `week 5`.
Therefore ID `aa` will be counted as `active_id` from `week 1` until `week 5`.

Another ID `bb` has open date on `week 1` but has no close date `NA`, which means ID was open since `week 1` but not closed until now (say now is `week 10`). Therefore ID `bb` will be counted as `active_id` from `week 1` until `week 10`.

```
# create weekly row
set.seed(1990)
have <- tibble(id = as.vector(outer(letters, letters, paste0))[1:48]
                        , open_week = sample(1:10,48, replace = T)
                        , age_week = sample(1:7,48, replace = T)) %>%
  mutate(close_week = open_week + age_week) %>%
  arrange(open_week)

# some are closed, some are not closed
# if not closed, set to NA
have$close_week[sample(c(TRUE, FALSE),48, replace = T, prob = c(0.3,0.7))] <- NA

# recalculate ID age for NA
have <- have %>%
  mutate(age_week = if_else(is.na(close_week), max(open_week) - open_week, age_week))

have

> have
# A tibble: 48 x 4
   id    open_week age_week close_week
   <chr>     <int>    <int>      <int>
 1 wa           10        0         NA
 2 sb            4        1          5
 3 ja            8        1          9
 4 cb            9        1         NA
 5 tb            9        1         NA
 6 hb           10        1         11
 7 pb            1        2          3
 8 la            3        2          5
 9 oa            6        2          8
10 rb            6        2          8
```

As you may notice, I think to generalize, I want to generate metrics on weekly basis (at least based on this reproducible data timeframe) for feature engineering purpose. I don't have the luxury to get weekly snapshots which would definitely simplify many of these operations. But I think it's very interesting (at least for me) how with these 3 columns alone (`ID`, `open time`, `close time`), I can re-generate weekly snapshots of the data.

```
# Daily time series
# these active_id numbers, close_id, median age week, active_growth_rate are fictionous, not actual values based on 
# the have data above
want <- tibble(open_week = seq(min(have$open_week),max(have$open_week))
               ,active_id = c(sample(10:18,length(open_week), replace = T))
               ,close_id = 20 - active_id
               ,median_age_week_active = c(sample(2:6,length(open_week), replace = T))
               ,median_age_week_closed = c(sample(2:6,length(open_week), replace = T)) 
               ,active_growth_rate = ((active_id - lag(active_id))/active_id) * 100)
> want
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   open_week active_id close_id median_age_week_a… median_age_week_c… active_growth_r…
       <int>     <int>    <dbl>              <int>              <int>            <dbl>
 1         1        12        8                  4                  2            NA   
 2         2        10       10                  3                  4           -20   
 3         3        11        9                  6                  6             9.09
 4         4        11        9                  4                  3             0   
 5         5        16        4                  3                  5            31.2 
 6         6        10       10                  3                  3           -60   
 7         7        14        6                  4                  5            28.6 
 8         8        10       10                  4                  2           -40   
 9         9        18        2                  4                  6            44.4 
10        10        18        2                  4                  4             0
```

Comment: Didn't the strategy work? I may try for different one, if this didn't work as expected?

Comment: @AnilGoyal, I'll get back to you soon, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Revised answer in view of update.

Follow this `tidyverse` strategy.  Explanation-

- generate a `seq` for first week to max of the week
- use `rowwise` for following operations

  - calculate cases opened during the week number - by just checking where the week number in sequence equals have$start
  - cases cases closed during the week similarly (here we have to use `na.rm = T`, so that conditional may return only T/F and no NA
  - collect all active cases in a list and calculate their distance from their start (but thing to be careful here, cases with NA in have$end also to be counted.)
  - similarly collect all closed cases in a list and calculate their distance
  - calculate length of active cases
  - calculate median of both the lists
- After ungrouping (rowwise) calculate growth percentage.

```
library(tidyverse)

seq_len(max(have$close_week, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  set_names("Week") %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(opened = sum(Week == have$open_week),
         closed = sum(Week == have$close_week, na.rm = T),
         act_ages_med = list(Week - have$open_week[Week >= have$open_week & 
                                                     Week < ifelse(is.na(have$close_week),
                                                                   max(have$close_week, na.rm = T) +1,
                                                                   have$close_week)]),
         cls_ages_med = list((Week - have$open_week[Week == have$close_week]) %>% na.omit()),
         active = length(act_ages_med),
         act_ages_med = median(act_ages_med),
         cls_ages_med = median(cls_ages_med)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(active_grth = (active - lag(active))*100/lag(active))

# A tibble: 14 x 7
    Week opened closed act_ages_med cls_ages_med active active_grth
   <int>  <int>  <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>  <int>       <dbl>
 1     1      8      0          0           NA        8       NA   
 2     2      5      0          1           NA       13       62.5 
 3     3      5      1          1            2       17       30.8 
 4     4      7      2          1            3       22       29.4 
 5     5      4      3          2            2       23        4.55
 6     6      4      3          2            4       24        4.35
 7     7      4      4          2.5          4       24        0   
 8     8      4      7          3            4       21      -12.5 
 9     9      3      3          3            5       21        0   
10    10      4      1          3            3       24       14.3 
11    11      0      3          4            2       21      -12.5 
12    12      0      4          5            7       17      -19.0 
13    13      0      1          6            6       16       -5.88
14    14      0      2          7.5          5.5     14      -12.5
```

#### Earlier Answer

Will this work?  In my opinion `age_week` isn't required at all

```
have %>% select(-age_week) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "event", values_to = "week") %>%
  mutate(event = factor(event, levels = c("open_week", "close_week"), ordered = T)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(week)) %>%
  arrange(week, event) %>%
  mutate(d = ifelse(event == "open_week", 1, -1),
         d = cumsum(d)) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(opened = sum(event == "open_week"),
            active = last(d),
            closed = sum(event == "close_week")) %>%
  mutate(active_gr_rate = (active - lag(active))*100/lag(active))

# A tibble: 14 x 5
    week opened active closed active_gr_rate
   <int>  <int>  <dbl>  <int>          <dbl>
 1     1      8      8      0          NA   
 2     2      5     13      0          62.5 
 3     3      5     17      1          30.8 
 4     4      7     22      2          29.4 
 5     5      4     23      3           4.55
 6     6      4     24      3           4.35
 7     7      4     24      4           0   
 8     8      4     21      7         -12.5 
 9     9      3     21      3           0   
10    10      4     24      1          14.3 
11    11      0     21      3         -12.5 
12    12      0     17      4         -19.0 
13    13      0     16      1          -5.88
14    14      0     14      2         -12.5
```

Note ids having NA status are assumed as open till date

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. The `age_week` is to help calculate the median `age_week` of active tickets on weekly basis. Let me update the post. I want to track, for every week, how many were active, closed and their statistics around `age_week` namely median.

Comment: Yes, the `median age` of active and closed for each week. I think you're right that `age_week` is not necessary in the `have` because we need to calculate the `age week` periodically. But otherwise the rest is good! So you're on the right track, I really appreciate your answer and time

Comment: There's one problem which is the case when there's no tickets opened or closed during a particular week. In this case, I think I have to use `complete` to ensure missing weeks repeat the values of the previous weeks? If not, the growth rate calculation will not be accurate since it won't capture stagnation weeks or off weeks.

Comment: if open week = 3, closed week = 3, I would consider 0 age. So if open week = x and closed week = x, the age is 0.

Comment: looks more complicated that I expected, I'll try against my data. Thanks!